# Different url path just for one article (Django)

Tags: python, django, path

I need to change url path just for one chosen article.
This is how it looks for all of my articles:

**site.com/articles/some-article**

I would like to create some condition just for one chosen article.
**site.com/chosen-article**

is it possible?

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/', include('mysite.articles.urls')),
]
```

Comment: yes. add a url pattern like `path('chosen-article', your_views_def_name_here, name='featured_article')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create that separate url path in your articles urls:

```
url(r'^some-article', SomeArticleView.as_view(), name='some-article'),
```

In the `SomeArticleView`, just return the wanted article.

EDIT: To better match the question, the url and view should be:

```
url(r'^chosen-article', ChosenArticleView.as_view(), name='chosen-article')
```

Finally, it can be whatever we chose.

Comment: Or do you mean `chosen-article`?